# GitHub Atom Feed Pagination

Tags: github, rss

It seems that GitHub is not offering the native Atom spec pagination. Is pagination even available in the GitHub RSS feed? And if not, does anyone know how to get more than 20 results?

I am, for example, fetching `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master.atom`, here I see the link elements

```
<link type="text/html" rel="alternate" href="https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master"/>
<link type="application/atom+xml" rel="self" href="https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commits/master.atom"/>
```

But there is no `rel=next` defined. I wondered whether anyone had any luck or knows whether it's possible to get more results or the next page.